# local variable inside parallel loops thread safety

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a variable (`cnt`) inside nested `parallel.foreach`. I run this program and apparently it works well. Does anybody know this code is really thread safe? Is it possible to define variable inside `parallel` loops?

Thank you.

```
    object obj = new object();
    int total=0;

    Parallel.For(0, 2, i =>
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 1000000, j =>
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            if ((arr[i, j] % 2) == 0)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref cnt);
            }
            lock (obj)
            {
                total= total+ (cnt / 2);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is thread safe - the only shared data (`total`) is properly synchronized.  It's threadsafe even without using `Interlocked.Increment` (ie: prior to your edit).

However, it is not *efficient*.

It would be far better to use the overload with [local initializer and finally delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783586.aspx).

```
int total=0;
Parallel.For(0, 2, 
{
    Parallel.For(0, 1000000, 
      local => 0,
      (j, state, local) =>
      {
        if ((arr[i, j] % 2) == 0)
        {
           ++local;
        }
        return local;
      },
      local => Interlocked.Increment(ref total, local)
    );
});
```

Comment: colud you please tell me how to change it to become efficient

Comment: I wonder if you can give me more information. Unfortunately, I receive this error 

The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For<TLocal>(int, int, System.Func<TLocal>, System.Func<int,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,TLocal,TLocal>, System.Action<TLocal>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @mohammad You need to make sure the local types are obvious - or specify the types explicitly.  I've blogged about this here: http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-4-imperative-data-parallelism-aggregation/

Comment: Thank you for informative blog. As you mentioned, local variable between various threads merge in final delegate. In my program I need to divide the local variable on 2. But when I use this code the result is wrong. 

lock (obj)
{          
    total = (total + (local/2));
}

I wonder if let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @mohammad Your original code doesn't make sense, though - because your "local" can only ever be 0 or 1 (you're only using it in a single loop iteration), so /2 will always be zero, since you're working with int values...  You might need to rethink the logic here.

Comment: I have modified the cnt and total variable data type to float in original and remove interlocked.increment then the result was half of the number of iteration. but when I try the second code every time I got different values. based on the logic it should not have happen because there are no difference in divide every value, group of value or all value on 2 but I got different values.

Comment: @mohammad You may want to put this as a new question.  Just make sure you're very clear about what you want it to do - I'd recommend including a non-parallel (working) version of what you're trying to acheive, and then let us help you parallelize it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This code is indeed safe because the `lock` statement acts as a full fencing operation.  It ensures that the increment operation is atomic and won't be subject to races from other threads

Comment: @pst the lock is necessary because of the use of `total`.  It is both read from and written to in the same statement.  Without the `lock` the thread could be interrupted after the read but before the write and hence end up with racy data